# Are tags broken?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

When I click on a tag, like "Yiddish", I get no results.  There certainly were questions with this tag before the migration.

Comment: +1. All the tags claim to have zero questions. But for a moment, I saw a correct number. So somewhere in a database is the correct number, in fact, which leads me to *guess* that the incorrect numbers are a temporary artifact of the migration. I assume someone at SE knows for sure.

Answer (score 5):

We have resynced the tags for all posts.  Sorry for the delay!